# Mongoose: Infinite scroll with filtering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I have these two models:

> User.js

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profiles",
  },
  following: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

> Profile.js

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  videoURL: {
    type: String,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profiles", ProfileSchema);
```

Here's an example of a `User` document:

```
{
  "following":  [
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_1"
      }
    },
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_2"
      }
    },
    {
      "profile":{}
    },
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_3"
      }
    },
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_4"
      }
    },
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_5"
      }
    },
    {
      "profile":{}
    },
    {
      "profile":{
        "videoURL":"video_url_6"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll of the videos of the users followed by the connected user.

> This means, I will have to filter user.following.profile.videoURL
> WHERE videoURL exists

Suppose, I will be loading two videos, by two videos:

- Response 1: ["video_url_1","video_url_2"]
- Response 2: ["video_url_3","video_url_4"]
- Response 3: ["video_url_5","video_url_6"]

Usually, infinite scroll is easy because all I have to load the documents 2 by 2 by order of storage without filtering on any field.
**Example: Displaying the followed users two by two in an infinite scroll**

```
User.findById(user_id).populate({
    path: "following",
    options: {
      skip: 2 * page,
      limit: 2,
    },
  });
```

But, now I have to perform filtering on each followed_user.profile.video, and return two by two. And I don't see how I can perform **BOTH** the filtering and the infinite scroll at the same time.

---

**NOTE:** According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> In general, there is no way to make populate() filter stories based on properties of the story's author. For example, the below query won't return any results, even though author is populated.

```
const story = await Story.
  findOne({ 'author.name': 'Ian Fleming' }).
  populate('author').
  exec();
story; // null
```

So I suppose, there is no way for me to use populate to filter based `user.followers`, based on each `user.follower.profile.videoURL`

Comment: can you explain what kind of filtering you want to do?

Comment: My bad,  I will have to filter user.following.profile.videoURL
 WHERE videoURL exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible with populate method, but you can try aggregation pipeline,

- `$match` `user_id` condition
- `$lookup` with aggregation pipeline in `users` collection for following
- `$match` following id condition
- `$lookup` with `profile` for `following.profile`
- `$match` `videoURL` should exists
- `$project` to show `profile` field and get first element using `$arrayElemAt`
- `$slice` to do pagination in `following`

```
let page = 0;
let limit = 2;
let skip = limit * page;

User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { following: "$following" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$following"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "profile",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "profile"
          }
        },
        { $match: { "profile.videoURL": { $exists: true } } },
        {
          $project: {
            profile: { $arrayElemAt: ["$profile", 0] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "following"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      following: {
        $slice: ["$following", skip, limit]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wK0yX46V-ue)

---

**Suggestion:**

You can improve your schema design,

- removing profile schema and add profile object in users collection, so you can achieve easily your requirement using populate method,
- put match condition in following populate for `videoURL` exists

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    profile: {
      type: {
         videoURL: {
           type: String
         }
      }
    },
    following: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users"
      }
    ]
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);

User.findById(user_id).populate({
  path: "following",
  match: {
    "profile.videoURL": { $ne: null }
  },
  options: {
    skip: 2 * page,
    limit: 2,
  }
});
```

Comment: What you posted is possible with populate. Problem is when I add filtering on profile.videoURL, then I didn't find a way to do it with populate. And you didn't mention it with your aggregate solution.

Comment: I told you this is the filtering criteria "user.following.profile.videoURL WHERE videoURL exists". I think what you have proposed, will return the first two users from following array and will only populate the profiles ones with the filtering criteria and then the second two users and so on and so forth. BUT, what I want it ONLY to return the users from following array WHERE following.profile.videoURL EXISTS.

Comment: i looked using populate but it is not possible, i have updated aggregation query as per your populate query.

Comment: i have added one suggestion if your are just planing and started your development you can improve the things, nosql rule is to avoid more collection, try to manage less collections. and avoid join.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really did not get your advice and how it's applicable here.

Comment: you can remove profile schema and add videoURL profile object to users collection. as per my updated solution at last and query, so this will save one lookup process in profile collection.

Comment: @turivishal
can you help me to solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118285/reactjs-and-mongoose-infinite-scrolling-implementation-issue

Answer (score 1):

*So what you want is table with infinite scroll and:*

**You can opt given ways to approach your problem** :

1. Load data (first page) into grid.
2. Set filter on a col.
3. Load data again, this time using the filter.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.